# Компиляция scss на webpack

Tags: webpack, scss

При компиляции scss в css на webpack в консоль выходит ошибка

Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```js
const path = require('path')
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = function (paths) {
    return {
        entry: './src/js/main.js',
        output: {
            filename: 'main.js',
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './assets/js')
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.scss$/,
                    include: paths,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        publicPath: './src/scss',
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    })
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    include: paths,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        fallback: 'style-loader',
                        use: 'css-loader'
                    })
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('./assets/css/main.css')
        ]
    }
}
```

Расположения файлов
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите пожалуйста я в этом еще начинающий

Comment: Сам Webpack в ошибке уже говорит, что проблема в include.

Comment: Что приходит в paths? По всей видимости туда приходит то, что webpack видеть в include не ожидает.